# Installing Java 8 on Ubuntu

Tags: java, linux, ubuntu, java-8

I am trying to install Java 8 on Ubuntu. Due to restrictions on download at my work place, I cannot install using apt-get. Hence, I downloaded the archive from Oracle's website. However, when I extracted it, there was only a file inside it. How to install using that file?

Comment: You're on the wrong platform, for an answer you can look here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/56104/how-can-i-install-sun-oracles-proprietary-java-jdk-6-7-8-or-jre

Comment: Are you sure you extracted it correctly? Be default it si packaged as .tar.gz. So if you just gunzip it, you will get the .tar file which you must unpack using `tar -xf` command

Comment: No, I got a .gz file, which I found weird. I extracted it using the package manager on ubuntu.

Comment: I realized it late that I shouldn't post it here. I am unable to delete it also. What should I do now?

Answer (score 1):

You'll no doubt have downloaded the tar file. To extract it:

```
tar -zxvf <file.tar.gz>
```

Where file.tar.gz is the file name.

Comment: I did not get a tar file, I got a .gz file. I extracted it using the ubuntu package manager.

Comment: You should have downloaded jdk-8u25-linux-i586.tar.gz or jdk-8u25-linux-x64.rpm from here: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html

Comment: I downloaded that only, but it downloads .gz file (check for yourself if you want, start the download and cancel it).

Comment: Right enough. What happens when you run tar -zxvf on that?

Comment: Ok i'll try that in a few minutes, but can the output be different than the one i got using ubuntu package manager?

Comment: I'd expect you to get the folder tree for the java sdk upon extracting the file. Incidentally, what file are you getting when you extract using the package manager?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65607/discussion-between-robert-bain-and-pravesh-jain).